# SWIG change type of field of a specific type for C#

Tags: c#, c++, swig

Let's say I have this in C/C++:

```
struct MyType {
   int foo;
   long other;   
};
```

I want to change "int" **ONLY** of field "foo" to bool in SWIG! How can I do this?

I don't want to change the original source. Normally if it were my sources, I would just change to bool!

Comment: should this be tagged c/c++ instead of C#? also: what happens if you... just change it?

Comment: Did it didideroo!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%apply` to use the `bool` typemaps on `int foo` to achieve what you want:

```
%module test
%apply bool { int foo };
%inline %{
struct MyType {
   int foo;
};
%}
```

In other more convoluted scenarios you'd have to write your own typemaps to support this, but since bool and int are implicitly convertible in C++ this will compile and work just fine out of the box.

Comment: Hello Flexo, thx for your answer is half the way! Must i manually declare all other members, because the rest is missing?!? Is there a way only to fix this specific field? The struct has much more fields! Regards

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson if you add the `%apply` to an existing, working interface then it already would work. The contents of the `%inline` is for a quick demonstration only. So you probably want to just use `%include` in your module to parse the real header file and then it'll all just work. The `%apply` directive as used above does this for all `int`s named 'foo' that happen after.

Comment: just using "%apply bool { int foo }" worked! How to limit only to a certain type? Thx

Comment: That is limited to only int's named foo. You can easily apply it to all ints, using `%apply bool { int }`, although that's probably not what you want to do, because it would then apply to all ints until you use %clear. If it were me I'd edit the C++ and add a typedef for the 'ints I want to pretend are bool in C#'. If the types you want to do this for are all only in one header file you can use the order of parsing to control where this happens. If not you can still do it using `%ignore` and some copy and paste. I can add any of those to the answer, but I'd strongly recommend the first way.